# when refreshing the page it showing error 404 page not found

Tags: angular2-routing, angular5

i get the same error even when i enter the URL with absolute path

But with Routing it is working fine

```
{ path: 'login' , component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'home' , component: HomeComponent},
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not generally an issue with angular, this issue occurs if your API uses the same port and when you refresh the page the request will go as **`Get: Login`** since your API does not have the matching valid param it will throw 404.

Hence that is displayed in the browser